# Python Library Installation Failed

Tags: python, pygame

I need to learn the popular `pygame` library. I have tried to install it on my mac, but when I tried:

```
pip3 install pygame
```

the result is:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

among other errors, what do I do?

Comment: You probably are missing some other library.  Show the »bunch of errors« at least.  And be aware that this isn't really a topic for SO, so your Q might get closed.

Comment: You need to give complete error. Additionally you can run the command with ` --verbose` option so the output would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't comment on your original question as I don't have the reputation, so I'll have to comment via an answer that isn't an answer. Can you please include the other errors that you mentioned in your question?

That would go a long way to helping solve your issue.